# Geoserver dynamically set bounding box / referencedEnvelope of datastore/layer when creating

Tags: java, geoserver

I am using `geoserver`. I extended `ContentDataStore` plugin to add csv data types as layers. I am using `geoserver rest api`, `HTTPUtils.put` method actually. When I do this the datastore gets created without boundingbox defined, unlike when it is created manually on `geoserver web application`. Therefore I get an exception when I try to use `wms-getCapabilities` method, because there is no boundingbox defined.

```
The getCapabilities query is below:
localhost:8090/geoserver/wms?Service=WMS&Version=1.1.1&Request=GetCapabilities

The inner exception is below:
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.geoserver.wms.capabilities.GetCapabilitiesTransformer$CapabilitiesTranslator.handleLatLonBBox(GetCapabilitiesTransformer.java:1349)
    at org.geoserver.wms.capabilities.GetCapabilitiesTransformer$CapabilitiesTranslator.handleLayer(GetCapabilitiesTransformer.java:901)
    at org.geoserver.wms.capabilities.GetCapabilitiesTransformer$CapabilitiesTranslator.handleLayerTree(GetCapabilitiesTransformer.java:826)
    ... 90 more
```

Is there a way to define boundingbox for a datastore/layer in `xxxDataStore or xxxDataStoreFactory` classes. So far I couldn't find any way to define while creating the datastore.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to it. I changed 2 classes. The first one is `xxxFeatureSource` which extends `ContentFeatureSource` (it's in ContentDataStore plugin) and the second one is `DataStoreFileResource`.

In `xxxFeatureSource` I overrided `ReferencedEnvelope getBoundsInternal()` method and implemented code which calculates my boundingBox.

In `DataStoreFileResource` I added this line;

```
ftInfo.setLatLonBoundingBox( bounds );
```

into the void `handlePut()` method, right after `ftInfo.setNativeBoundingBox( bounds )`.

Now I can use getCapabilities method after adding my DataStore via GeoServer rest api.

Hope it helps others too.